# Generate a combination of word list from string

Tags: java, string, generate

I want to generate a list of keywords  from given string in java

e.g. " this is my string"

generated list

"this is my"
"this is"
"this"
"string"
"my string"
"is my string"

Comment: Please show us your attempt

Comment: And also the rules of generation. E.g. would "is my" a valid output?

Comment: You should search for it, then try it, and then ask if you are stuck.

Comment: Number of generated keys should be 4! or 24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this one:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] wordArray = "this is my string".split(" ");
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    int n = wordArray.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
       for (int j = i; j < n; j++) {
            result.add(
                IntStream.rangeClosed(i, j)
                    .mapToObj(v -> wordArray[v])
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")));
        }
    }
    result.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If there is no special rules for input.

Comment: @thturk it worked, but you should research and understand every statement in this answer, otherwise you'll end up asking your next assignment question in SO.